# Why use setattr() and getattr() built-ins?

Tags: python, python-3.x

From reading the docs, I understand exactly what [getattr()](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#getattr) and [setattr()](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#setattr) do. But it also says explicitly that `getattr(x, 'foobar')` is equivalent to `x.foobar` and `setattr(x, 'foobar', 123)` is equivalent to `x.foobar = 123`.

So why would I use them?

Comment: If you can't think of a good reason to use them, you probably don't have one. :) But one day, you've find yourself with an attribute name in a string variable (e.g., from user input, or computed by processing some JSON from a server, or whatever) and want to get the attribute with the name given in that variable, and that's when you'll use it.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75531642/when-is-it-necessary-to-define-getattr-and-setattr-methods-for-a-cla

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Because you can use a dynamic variable too:

```
somevar = 'foo'
getattr(x, somevar)
```

You can't do that with regular attribute access syntax.

Note that `getattr()` also takes an optional default value, to be returned if the attribute is *missing*:

```
>>> x = object()
>>> getattr(x, 'foo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'foo'
>>> getattr(x, 'foo', 42)
42
```

Using `getattr()` you can pull the attribute name from something else, not a literal:

```
for attrname in dir(x):
    print('x.{} = {!r}'.format(attrname, getattr(x, attrname))
```

or you can use `setattr()` to set dynamic attributes:

```
for i, value in enumerate(dynamic_values):
    setattr(i, 'attribute{}'.format(i), value)
```

Comment: Good explanation. But it's worth noting that often, if you think you want this, you don't; the attribute should have been a value in a dictionary rather than an attribute in the first place.

Comment: @abarnert: Not always. There are usecases to handle dynamic transformations on existing objects. Or looking up attributes that could be missing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes, that's why I said "often". If they were _never_ useful, they wouldn't be in the language at all. As a good rule of thumb: If you normally want to access something statically, but occasionally dynamically, use an attribute with occasional `getattr`; if you normally want to access it dynamically, but occasionally statically, use a dict with occasional literal keys.

Comment: In my current project codebase I count 12 modules using `getattr()` (not counting tests); 4 of those are façades; the rest use `getattr()` to handle optional attributes, returning a default value if missing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I've actually got more `__getattr__` instances in my code than `getattr`… but yes, I use it too. The first time I want `getattr` somewhere, I stop and ask myself whether the thing really should be an attribute. Sometimes the answer is "yes" (or, occasionally, "no, but there's too much spaghetti at this point to fix it…"). But it's always worth thinking about it (except in the cases where it's obvious—e.g., you're writing reflective code for debugging).

Comment: @MartijnPieters "In my current project codebase I count 12 modules", as a point of reference, what type of code is it? As a developer for one-off software for scientific projects I've never had to use it so I would be interested to see where it comes up in a live setting.

Comment: actually, i would argue that attributes are really useful for one other reason: you can tab-complete them in the console. if you're mostly using python interactively, then this is a big win. but usually, though, if i do that, i try to implement a pattern where both the attributes and `__getitem__` are both defined, so x.attr and x['attr'] are identical.

Comment: @Hooked: An enterprise security product central management package built on Django.

Answer (score 13):

You use them if the attribute you want to access is a variable and not a literal string.  They let you parameterize attribute access/setting.

There's no reason to do `getattr(x, 'foobar')`, but you might have a variable called `attr` that could be set to "foobar" or "otherAttr", and then do `getattr(x, attr)`.

Answer (score 7):

Another case probably shows that they are not totally identical:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self)：
        self.__var = 10
        setattr(self, '__var2', 100)

a = A()
print(a.__var2)
# 100
print(a.__var)
# AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute '__var'
```

At least, `setattr` is not identical to `.`.

Answer (score 2):

I find it most useful when there is a possibility that the object whose attribute you need might be `None`. Exemplified below;

```
obj = None
attr_val = getattr(obj, 'anyvar', None) #This is not an error.
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between `setattr` and `.`, not documented yet:

```
class X:

    def __init__(self, value1, value2):
        self.__non_private_name_1 = value1
        setattr(self, '__non_private_name_2', value2)


>>> x = X('Hi', 'Bye')
>>> x.__dict__
{'_X__non_private_name_1': 'Hi', '__non_private_name_2': 'Bye'}
```

The latter one, when used to set a dunder value (ones with double underscores) adds a single underscore `_` + `self.__class__.__name__`(i.e. `X`) to the beginning of the string in right side of `.` and sets the attribute named with the resulting string(i.e. `_X__non_private_name_1`).

Answer (score 0):

i think python has deep thinking to support setattr() and getattr() on instance.

Imaging that you have an instance like a baby, who knows nothing when it is born. i.e. there is no any attributes in that instance.
As long as the baby grows up, he/she learns more and more skills, so that setattr() is used to make it work, and it makes no one identical even if all the baby instances are created from the same class.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into another use case that requires the use of `setattr`: decorating imported recursive functions. If you implement the recursive computation of the Fibonacci numbers in a file `fibo.py`:

```
def fib(n):
    return n if n < 2 else fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

and you then want to take advantage of `lru_cache` in `main.py` when you import that function, then the straightforward way that works within `fibo.py` does not work in `main.py`:

```
from fibo import fib
from functools import lru_cache
fib = lru_cache(fib)
print(fib(42))  # takes ages
```

The `setattr` way works however:

```
import fibo
from functools import lru_cache
setattr(fibo, "fib", lru_cache(fibo.fib))
print(fibo.fib(42))  # lightning fast
```

EDIT: well, it turns out that the straightforward way works too if you import the whole module:

```
import fibo
from functools import lru_cache
fibo.fib = lru_cache(fibo.fib)
print(fibo.fib(42))  # lightning fast
```