# How to dynamically call class.function(value) in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, getattr

OK, so I have a string, `x = module.class.test_function(value)`, and I want to call it and get the response. I've tried to use `getattr(module.class, test_function)(value)` yet it gives the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'module' has no attribute 'test_function'
```

I'm new to these things in python, how would I do this?

Comment: Can you show this as a running script? Is `test_function` supposed to be a variable with the function name in it? What is `thing.class`? Does `print(thing.class)` give a hint?

Comment: It looks like `thing.class` is a module so the question is, where did it come from?

Comment: Yes test_function is a variable with the function name in it

Comment: The error message says that `module.class` is in fact a module called "module" and it doesn't have a variable called "test_function". There really isn't much else we can say without more information.

Comment: But what is the syntax of calling class.function(value) when class and function and value are variables cointaining the class and function names and what to input to the function.

Comment: You have the right syntax. Python took the object in `module.class` and tried to find whatever was in `test_function` but it failed. `module.class` is a module called "module" and `test_function` is the string "test_function". You could `print(module.class.__dict__)` t osee what's in it and `print(module.class.__file__)` to see where it is.

Comment: But you see, it thinks that test_functuon is the function name. But it's a variable

Comment: Its a variable with the string "test_function" in it. At least that's what the error message says.

Comment: Add `print('test_function:', test_function)` to see if that is the case.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I've understood the question correctly, but I've added an example answer that shows how to do a dynamic import with `getattr` below.  Does that address your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a file `my_module.py`:

```
def my_func(greeting):
    print(f'{greeting} from my_func!')
```

You can import your function and call it normally like this:

```
>>> from my_module import my_func
>>> my_func('hello')
hello from my_func!
```

Alternatively, if you want to import the function dynamically with `getattr`:

```
>>> import my_module
>>> getattr(my_module, 'my_func')
<function my_func at 0x1086aa8c8>
>>> a_func = getattr(my_module, 'my_func')
>>> a_func('bonjour')
bonjour from my_func!
```

I would only recommend this style if it's required by your use case, for instance, the method name to be called not being known until runtime, methods being generated dynamically, or something like that.

A good answer that explains `getattr` in more detail is - [Why use setattr() and getattr() built-ins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19123707/why-use-setattr-and-getattr-built-ins) and you can find a bit more at http://effbot.org/zone/python-getattr.htm.