# List comprehension including attribute on member that can be None

Tags: python

Sorry if the title is a bit unclear, I didn't know how to really summarize the issue.

If I some list of objects like this:

```
class Item:
    x = 0
    y = OptionalMember() # this can be None

class OptionalMember:
    z = 1
```

And I want to use a list comprehension to collect from a list of `Item` objects, but including the value `z` when `y` is present, otherwise just taking `None`. If `y` was always present, of course it would simply be

```
xs = [(item.x, item.y.z) for item in items]
```

but then

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'z'

so how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `valueIfTrue if confition else valueIfFalse` inside the list comprehension

```
xs = [(item.x, item.y.z if item.y else None) for item in items]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) and provide a `default` value as the third argument.

```
xs = [(item.x, getattr(item.y, "z", None)) for item in items]
```

Comment: That also works, but seems less readable and "pythonic" than the other answer. Is there some case where this is "better" or actually required?

Comment: in your opinion how is this less Pythonic? they are in essence the same. you can read more here —> https://stackoverflow.com/a/19123719/6817835

Comment: There **is** a case where you have to it like this: If `item.y` can be **undefined**, you will get an error when calling `if item.y` – edit: Sorry, I did a mistake here. In this case, you'd have to use `getattr` to get the `y` attribute from item, so `getattr(item, 'y', None)` so it's not necessarily useful here.

Comment: also the other answer since it tests the truthiness of the value would fail in the case where item.y is anything but None or the OptionallMapping object