Python assign inherited class
I have a class A that has many attributes, lets call them a,b,c,...,z
Then I have a class B that inherites from A. Inside a function in B I want to set all the self attributes of A to another instance of A.
class B(A):
    def set_A(obj:A):
        self.a = obj.a
        self.b = obj.b
        ...
        self.z = obj.z

Is there any way to do it without wrting each of As properties and setting them one by one?

You could iterate the attributes of obj and set them on self, but this way you will have to weed out all the attributes you don't want to copy. Do you have a sort of formal definition anywhere of the attributes you want to copy? Perhaps as type hints on A or such?

Just to make sure I got this right, copy.copy and copy.deepcopy will create new objects. That's different because in your case the other instance already exists and you want to only copy A attributes and not B attributes.

perhaps using obj.__dict__ you might deep copy it or iterate it's key value pairs. Alternatively, perhaps copy.deepcopy()

@JonSG I guess __dict__ could help here since it will return me which properties I need to set, I'm not sure how I would set them though since it will be strings. Also I don't understant how copy or deepcopy will help here.

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/19123707/476

@deceze yes, this combined with __dict__ solves it.
